# is there any transformation T from $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ for this

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

given that $$T(1,-1,1)=(1,0)\qquad T(1,1,1)=(0,1)$$ and we have to find is there any transformation  $T: R^3 \to R^2$, please help me. I know we can construct another vector using $\qquad c_1T\alpha_1+c_2T\alpha_2 = T(c_1\alpha_1+c_2\alpha_2)$ then what to do?

Comment: There's infinitely many transformation just define $T$ on a third vector such that the three vectors of $\Bbb R^3$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
v_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\-1\\1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
v_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
v_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Then we may define $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ by putting 
$$
T(v_1)= e_1,\quad T(v_2)=e_2,\quad T(v_3)=\mathbf 0
$$
and extending linearly.

To compute a formula for $T$, note that
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0\\
\end{bmatrix}&=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+v_3 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}&= -\frac{1}{2}v_1+\frac{1}{2}v_2+0\cdot v_3 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix} &= \frac{1}{2}v_1+\frac{1}{2}v_2-v_3
\end{align*}
This gives the formula
$$
T
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-y +z \\
y+z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is one such linear transformation T. Let A be the associated 2 by 3 matrix with entries are:

a(11) = 0, a(12) = -1/2, a(13) = 1/2

a(21) = 1/2, a(22) = 1/2, a(23) = 0.

You can check that A*(1,-1,1) = (1,0) and A*(1,1,1) = (0,1)