# how to show that a linear transformation exists between two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there a linear transformation $T$ from $\Bbb{R^3}$ into $\Bbb{R^2}$ such that $T(1,-1,1)=(1,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)=(0,1)$

My try:
According to me i think that I have to show that $(1,-1,1),(1,1,1)$ form a basis but according to my computations they don't. Now since they don't form a basis i cannot write the vector (1,0,0) in terms of these two vectors. So because of this at least there will  one vector in $\Bbb{R^3}$ who wont have a linear transformation in $\Bbb{R^2}$ since by the given mapping i cannot represent the standard basis vectors. Therefore there isnt a linear transformation with such kind of a mapping. Am i right?

sorry but i found a duplicate over here
 :-[is there any transformation T from $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ for this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713986/is-there-any-transformation-t-from-bbb-r3-to-bbb-r2-for-this?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry if what  am doing is utter nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the two given vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ to a basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^3$ by arbitrarily adding a third linearly independent vector (say, $\vec e_1$) that is mapped to any other vector (say, $\vec 0$) by $T$. Express each vector in the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$ and use the linearity of $T$ to find each column of the standard matrix for $T$. For example, notice that since:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It follows that the third column of the standard matrix is:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 \\ 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Indeed, it's not too hard to verify that the linear tranformation $T\colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(\vec x) = A\vec x$ where:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies the desired property.

Comment: how did you get $\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
- \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 \\ 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$ this?@Adriano

Comment: @Rememberme Apply $T$ to both sides of the previous equation and use the fact that $T$ is linear.

Comment: and also how did you end upon the conclusion that $A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$@Adriano

Comment: @Rememberme Did it make sense how I found the third column? Recall that the standard matrix of $T$ is simply:
$$
A = [T(\vec e_1) ~~~ T(\vec e_2) ~~~ T(\vec e_3)]
$$
To find each column of $A$, simply apply $T$ to each vector in the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: OH okay but i havent yet been introduced to linear transformation with matrices.....@Adriano

Comment: thanks for the answer @Adriano

Answer (score -1):

define $T$ by $$T(1,-1,1)=(1,0), T(1,1,1) =(0,1),T(1,0,0)= (0,0).$$ observe that $a=(1,-1,1),b=(1,1,1),c=(1,0,0)$ forms a basis for $R^3.$ now extend $T$ by defining $$T(\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c)= \alpha T(a) + \beta T(b)$$ and you have your linear transformation $T.$

Comment: But how can i just define it to be this i have to use just the following given informatiion@abel